# Why does github try and ssh me into a different account?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am trying to ssh into github. I have generated an ssh key in my .ssh directory on my computer. Then I added it that key into the ssh keys section of github. But when I type ssh -T git@github.com it successfully authenticates into a differnt github account with an old ssh key that I no longer have in my .ssh folder. I don't understand how it does this. It does say agent admitted to failure to sign using the key before it successfully ssh's into the wrong github account.

Comment: You can list the keys known to ssh agent by typing `ssh-add -l`. If it knows about your old key, it would be shown there.

Comment: ok it doesnt. It only sees the new key. I signed onto my old github account and deleted the key. Now it just says agent admitted to failure to sign using the key. permission denied (publickey)

Comment: using ssh-add worked. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: Don't forget to answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by running `ssh-add`before trying to ssh in.